# How can we realistically vaccinate our way to herd immunity?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

So I've been keeping track of the number of people have received a vaccine for COVID-19 in the US. If we want to vaccinate 70%-90% of the population, per latest Dr. Fauci's estimates, then we need to vaccinate between `243,285,000` to `312,795,000` people (assuming 331 Million in the US).  Studies suggest immunity might last around 8 months (for infected people).  Which means from Dec 26th going forward we'd need to vaccinate `1,194,755` - `1,538,863` people per day to reach the 70% - 90% by July 2021 (assuming 7 days / week).  I believe the US government's goal is to reach `100,000,000` people vaccinated by end of April which would require a modest `925,926` vaccinations per day.

So far as of Dec 26, 2020 `1,944,585` people have received vaccine in the US.  Given that we started to vaccinate people on Dec 14, 2020 that means we are roughly vaccinating around `162,000 / day`.  Obvious about a factor of 1/10 the rate we want to be doing it if we want to reach the 8 month immunity window.

I'm estimating between `50,000 - 72,000` technicians would be needed to deliver shots every day to reach the goals above.  That's assuming 32 shots per day per technician and 1.5x people so people can have a 5 day work week and added redundancy for sick leave, time off, etc.  Also that's excluding clerical staff and support staff.  To me that doesn't sound impossibly high.

So the question is are there enough people to administer a 10x number of vaccines per day to reach herd immunity?  How much of the health care staff would be required to administer that many doses per day (as opposed to doing other health care related activities - curing cancer, birthing babies, treating trauma, ER visits, etc).  Or how is the government going to have enough people to administer the shot in people's arms if you can't rely on the capacity of health care workers alone?  Can states individually produce this amount of staff to administer the vaccine?

Comment: "Studies suggest immunity from these vaccines last around 8 months" - we have absolutely no idea how long immunity will last.

Comment: As I said studies thus far, 2 in fact, suggest it's around 8 months.  https://www.cidrap.umn.edu/news-perspective/2020/12/two-studies-find-covid-19-antibodies-last-8-months

Comment: These are studies of infected individuals, not vaccinated ones. They tested for presence of particular circulating antibodies, not immunity to infection. 8 months is the longest time frame they studied (remember, this virus hasn't been around that long; it would not be physically possible to test anything beyond about a year, and such a study would need to involve the few people known to have been infected at the very beginning).

Comment: Point taken, but that's the best information we have right now on how long immunity will last.  Experts are hoping vaccinated people will last longer, but as you point out who knows.  So, I'm assuming it's the same for vaccinated vs infected just so we can work out the math and formulate an idea of what a plan might have to look like.  If I'm wrong and vaccinated people are longer fire up the sunshine and moonbeams.  If it's 16 months then cut every estimate in half, 32 months - quarter it.

Comment: I'm trying to find a question here that's about medical science and I'm just not seeing it. I see a question about logistics with some politics sprinkled on top, but no medical science.

Comment: Sure I had a bit of a hard time figuring out where such a question belonged.  Of the forums that had questions on covid-19 it was this one or mathematics (surprisingly not stats).  And since this has to deal with staffing I wasn't sure mathematics would care or really know actual details about capacity and existing plans.  Plus this touches on what plans may have been formed already, or not and it would be more likely someone related to the medical field might know more details.  So I decided to post it here.